# XamGrid - Set GroupByRowStyle based on indentation level

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I am using the XamGrid by Infragistics (not their XamDataGrid).

Does anyone know how I can set the GroupByRowStyle based on the level of the group?

As you drill down into each group the next group down needs to be a lighter shaded colour.

The other thing to point out is that I need this style to change if the grouping order is changed.

Any help appreciated.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else needs to do this, I eventually got this working by setting a style trigger  to set the visibility of the contentControl based on the grouping level:

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- The top group should not display the content -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=igPrim:GroupByCellControl}, Path=Cell.Row.Manager.GroupByLevel}" Value="0">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="ContentControl.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```